# 2 Maccabees 1:36: original version of the verse

Tags: etymology, 2-maccabees

Some translations of 2 Maccabees 1:36 seem to explain the etymology of the term "Naphtha":

> Nehemi′ah and his associates called this “nephthar”, which means purification, but by most people it is called naphtha.

Other translations, instead of "naphtha" report a proper noun (eg.: "Neftài" in an Italian translation), indicating, perhaps, the name of a town.

What was the original term?

Clearly, a word sounding like "naphtha" was used to indicate that "thick water", but was it a word already in use explicitly for that, or its name was given according to something else?

May it be assumed that this verse was added in 2 Maccabees 1:36 to attempt an explanation of an etymology, like often happens in the Old Testament?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Maccabees was originally written in Koine Greek.  Here is that original Greek text of 2 Macc 1:36 -

> προσηγόρευσαν δὲ οἱ περὶ τὸν Νεεμίαν τοῦτο **νέφθαρ**, ὃ διερμηνεύεται
> Καθαρισμός· καλεῖται δὲ παρὰ τοῖς πολλοῖς **Νεφθαεί**. = And Neemias
> called this thing **Nephthar**, which is as much as to say, a
> cleansing: but many men call it **Nephi**. (Brenton)

According to the text itself, "nephthar" means "a cleansing".